# Why a filter of data table turn into values instead of data?

Tags: r, database, filter

I have a data table that I would like to filter by years. Therefore, I wrote the next command:

```
Gravity_V202211 <- readRDS("G:/My Drive/PhD/Methodology/Netunim/Gravity_V202211.rds")
Gravityfilter1 <- Gravity_V202211$year> 1969 & Gravity_V202211$year < 2015
view(Gravityfilter1)
```

I did not get a new data table, which is named `Gravityfilter1`, but a values with Large logical instead of observations and variables?
How can I create a data table instead?

Comment: You need to subset the data, not just provide the conditions (which will return `TRUE` or `FALSE`) - try: `Gravity_V202211[Gravity_V202211$year> 1969 & Gravity_V202211$year < 2015, ]`

Answer (score 1):

You can figure out this one yourself if you worked with some dummy, small data.
The line `Gravity_V202211$year> 1969 & Gravity_V202211$year < 2015` produces a vector of boolean, because you have a condition checking statement. You **could not get anything but boolean** out of such a statement.

If you wanted to get your data filtered, then you have to provide the boolean to the original table. Something like `show X when condition Y is satisfied`.

Imagine a small data.frame `a`:

```
a = data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 2:4)
```

You can filter the data frame *when* `x == 2` like this:

```
a[a$x == 2, ]
```

(for your own comprehension, write `a$x == 2`. Do you see the result?)

You want to check if a variable is **between** two values. Package `data.table` has a very convenient function / expression for those cases:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Gravity_V202211) # converts your table into a data.table
Gravity_V202211[year %between% c(1969, 2015), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest to perform this kind of operation using the 'dplyr' package.

```
library(dplyr)    

Gravityfilter1 <- filter(Gravity_V202211, year > 1969, year < 2015)
View(Gravityfilter1)
```

Also for common queries such as this, it's best to search Google and this site for the answer before posting (this will definitely have already been answered). See https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/ for more info on useful functions for simple data manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you could use `between`, since it uses x >= left & x <= right, we need to use 1968 instead of 1969 and 2014 instead of 2015

```r
Gravityfilter1 <- filter(Gravity_V202211, between(year, 1968, 2014))
```